# Problem to Update DATABASE on mySQL for JAVAFX Project

Tags: mysql, javafx

I running my program to update data in tableview for my java crud project with javafx. But the database on mySQL isn't updating. Here the code when i press update button (made by scene builder):

```
@FXML
private void handleUpdateDataButton(ActionEvent event) {
        // Mendapatkan data terpilih dari tabel
        DataBarang selectedData = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

        if (selectedData != null) {
            // Mengambil nilai dari input fields
            String namaBarang = namaBarangField.getText();
            int nomorBarang = Integer.parseInt(nomorBarangField.getText());
            int jumlah = Integer.parseInt(jumlahField.getText());
            String spesifikasi = spesifikasiField.getText();

            // Mendapatkan tanggal saat ini
            String tanggal = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));

            // Memanggil metode untuk mengupdate data ke dalam database
            if (updateDataBarang(namaBarang, nomorBarang, jumlah, spesifikasi, tanggal)) {
                System.out.println("Data berhasil diupdate");
                // Menyembunyikan pane setelah update
                PaneTambah.setVisible(false);
                // Memuat ulang data setelah penghapusan
                refreshTableData();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Gagal mengupdate data");
                // Tambahkan logika untuk menangani kesalahan penghapusan data
            }
        } else {
            showAlert("Peringatan", "Pilih data yang akan diupdate");
        }
    }

private boolean updateDataBarang(String namaBarang, int nomorBarang, int jumlah, String spesifikasi, String tanggal) {
        String query = "UPDATE `barang` SET "
                + "`Nama_Barang`=?,"
                + "`Nomor_Barang`=?,"
                + "`Jumlah`=?,"
                + "`Spesifikasi`=?,"
                + "`Tanggal`=? WHERE Nomor_Barang = ?";

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
             PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
             preparedStatement.setString(1, namaBarang);
             preparedStatement.setInt(2, nomorBarang);
             preparedStatement.setInt(3, jumlah);
             preparedStatement.setString(4, spesifikasi);
             preparedStatement.setString(5, tanggal);
             preparedStatement.setInt(6, nomorBarang);

            int rowsAffected = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            return rowsAffected > 0; // Jika ada baris yang terpengaruh, data berhasil diupdate
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

please help, thank you in advance.

Comment: After executing executeUpdate(), it is necessary to execute commit() to commit the transaction

Answer (score 0):

1. After executing executeUpdate, the commit method needs to be called to commit the transaction in order to persist the updated data to the database.
2. If the database connection is not properly closed, it may result in data not being updated. After executing executeUpdate, the close method needs to be called to close the database connection.
3. When creating a database connection, the automatic commit property of the connection can be set. If automatic commit is not set, you need to manually call the commit method to commit the transaction.